# How can I remove or disable "Unlock from launcher" in the Quicklist of a Launcher-Icon?

Tags: launcher, quicklists

I'm maintaining the PC of an old relative. The person shall **not** have the possibility **to unlock a Launcher-Icon** by means of "*Unlock from launcher*" in the Quicklist (in former Ubuntu versions it was named uncheck "*Keep in Launcher*").

Is it possible to **remove or disable** (greyed out) "*Unlock from launcher*" in the Quicklist of a Launcher-Icon?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It seems there exists **no way** to remove or disable “*Unlock from launcher*” in the Quicklist of a Launcher-Icon.

But I found a **workaround** that **saves the current order** of the icons in the Launcher and - in the case that an icon was mistakenly removed from the Launcher - **restores the order** after every start, reboot or login.

**Step 1**: **Save the current order of the icons in the Launcher**: Start *Terminal* (Ctrl+Alt+T) and enter the command `gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites > starter.icons` (this will save the order in the file *starter.icons* in your home-directory).

**Step 2: Create a script** in your home-directory by means of the command `gedit ~/starter.icons_restore.sh` and type the following text:

```
#!/bin/bash
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "$(cat starter.icons)"
```

*Save* the file and *close Gedit*.

**Step 3: Make the file executable** by means of the command `chmod +x ~/starter.icons_restore.sh`

**Step 4: Make a new entry in the Startup Applications**: Klick on the wheel in the top-right corner and chose *Startup Applications...* > Press *Add* > *Name*: Restore Launcher-Icons > *Command*: `/home/<YourUsername>/starter.icons_restore.sh`

From now on after every start, reboot or login, the order of the icons in the launcher will be restored according the information in the file *~/starter.icons*.

**P.S**: Instead of Step 4 you can also **create a [Desktop-Starter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)** with the command `/home/<YourUsername>/starter.icons_restore.sh`

**PP.S**: Good news: In the case you have manually edited the **quicklist** of a Launcher-Icon, the **amendments will be preserved** even if the icon is (mistakenly) removed. That means, after restoring, the quicklist still contains all amendments.